# sudo to kill output of ps, awk, xargs

Tags: command-line, sudo, awk, xargs

I want to kill root owned processes containing foo in the process name

```
sudo sh -c "ps aux | grep [f]oo  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15"
```

this command fail as awk and xargs are ignored.

```
sudo sh -c "ps aux | grep [f]oo  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15"
```

so kill receives bad args

```
kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.
```

Comment: Does your system not have pkill?

Comment: What have you tried (to get this to work)?  Standard trouble-shooting technique: break things down to see what part(s) are not behaving the way you expect.  Does `ps aux | grep "[f]oo"` show you the processes you’re interested in?  Does `ps aux | grep "[f]oo" | awk '{print $2}'` show you their PIDs?  (P.S. I recommend putting `[f]oo` in quotes.)

Comment: So how about `ps aux | grep "[f]oo" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs /bin/echo kill –15`?

Comment: And what do you mean “`awk` and `xargs` are ignored”?  Are you getting error messages that you’re not telling us?

Comment: If I run the commands without  "|kill"  the output on the screen is not formatted by awk.  sudo sh -c "ps aux | grep [f]oo  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, and `kill` will complain, but it works (for me, at least):

```
sudo kill `ps -ae | grep foo` &>/dev/null
```

The `&>/dev/null` part is optional; include it if you do not want to see all of `kill`'s complaints.

I know there is probably a better way of doing this, but this is what I use.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned `pgrep` and `pkill` are your friends:

```
sudo pkill `pgrep -u root foo`
```

If for some reason you do not have `pgrep` and `pkill`, you can do something like this:

```
for n in $(ps -u root | grep foo | cut -d ' ' -f 2); do sudo kill $n; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your real problem lies in the quoting. Within double quotes $2 is expanded before it is even passed to sh. The single quotes as used in your code do not insulate this because they are just quoted characters. Try one of these quoting methods:

`sh -c 'ps aux | grep [f]oo | awk '\''{ print $2 }'\'`

`sh -c $'ps aux | grep [f]oo | awk \'{ print $2 }\''`

`sh -c "ps aux | grep [f]ox | awk '{ print \$2 }'"`

Comment: Very useful, thankyou  very  much

Answer (score 1):

This way you can avoid double quoting issues. The result should be the same.

```
sudo kill -15 $(ps aux | grep '[f]oo' | awk '{print $2}')
```